# BufferWriter automatic flushing

Tags: java, flush, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I would like to know how long should I write in order to exceed the Buffer and hence automatically flushing the buffer on its own.

```
try
    {
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file),1);

            br.write("How much should I write in order to get it flushed without using .flush() nor close());
```

I am aware that close() automatically flush the buffer, but I am also aware that once the buffer is full and it receives more input it flushes it and then gets more input.. 
So again how much should I write in order to overcome the `1` size I specified in the constructor?
I have typed quite a bit However no result. 
PS: It's just to understand how the buffer works behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source of BufferedWriter?

Comment: Ohh, you are passing 1 as the bufferesize!

Comment: @rocketboy I used the constructor which allows me to specify the buffer size. And I checked also the source code as Kayman suggested and I saw that it actually create a char [] of size 1 so 01 after 2 chars it should flush but it does not happen.

Comment: Again, I am aware of the methods flush() and that within close() it flushes the buffer. However I don't want to use those methods on purpose to check how the Buffer works behind the scenes. By creating it with size = 1. It does not reflect the expected result

Comment: @Kayaman I checked, however it does not help much.  I saw in the sourcecode that it actually create a char [] of size 1 so 01 after 2 chars it should flush but it does not happen.

Comment: Well, it does all flushing and reading at runtime ofcourse. So when, on runtime it is reading 1 char then flushing then reading then flushing. Unless you override the flush and increment a counter, how do you plan to measure it?

Comment: @rocketboy I see in the file that nothing has been written into

Comment: I don't think that `BufferedWriter` is the stream chain's endpoint. Just because one of the streams in teh chain is flushed, does not guarantee that all the subsequent streams will flush too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looking at the Java source for any of the `BufferedWriter`'s `write` methods, you'll see `flushBuffer` method calls, which, in turn, calls `out.write(...)`. It does not call `out.flush()`.

What this means in more understandable terms:

Yes, it will flush after every character, but it will flush it to the underlying `Writer` (`FileWriter` in this case), not the actual file (as opposed to `flush`, which calls `flushBuffer` as well as `out.flush()`, flushing the underlying `Writer` to the actual file). `FileWriter` has its own schedule of when flushing happens (I'm not entirely sure, but I think the buffer size is the default defined in `StreamEncoder`, which is `8192`).

Comment: Yep it uses the defaul buffer size (FileWriter).. ok Cool although the source code of write(String s) seems to set back the buffer size to standard even though created with (Writer, int size).

Comment: In an overall view it makes sense also because the constructor taking the size is just in case one needs a bigger buffer than the standard one.. not if you need a smaller one (which does not make much sense). However there are two default buffers one wrapped into another so it's going to be 16384 the total thing available before raw flushing. Right?

Comment: @Rollerball Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Writer` contract. You should always call close() when you are done with a Writer so it can finish writing its data and close it's resources (in this case a File handler to `file`).

Other than that, implementation details such as buffer size should not concern you since they can change in future versions of Java or if you change which implementation of Writer you use.

Also, the whole point of a Buffered Writer is to reduce the number of times data is actually written to disk by collecting large chunks of data into a buffer and then writing the entire buffer at once.  Creating a BufferedWriter with a buffer of 1 defeats this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from BufferedWriter source code it creates a char buffer

```
private char cb[];
```

with default size = 8192. Before writing a next char it checks if the buffer is full and if true it flushes it.

```
...
if (nextChar >= nChars)
    flushBuffer();
cb[nextChar++] = (char) c;
...
```

that is, if you created BufferWriter with default buffer size you need to write 8193 chars to make it flush

Comment: `write(String)` doesn't call `write(int)` (which it seems is where you copied that code from)...

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev So why I don't get anything printeted in the file without calling flush() or close(). I set the buffer size as 1 so it should take max 2 chars and then flush it. It does not do that.